# GCP Cloud Build link repository doesn't lists all Github repositories

Tags: google-cloud-build

I created a Github connection in the GCP Cloud Build

[image]

there are 3 repositories in my Github a/c but the Link Repository option shows only 1. I'm not able to figure out why it doesn't list all the 3 repositories from where I can choose 1. Can you please help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your issue . I assume that, from the image you shared you have just attached   your github account. but, not your repositories.

Check  the below image  to find out how to link repositories, after following the steps, you can find all of your repositories while creating triggers.

And also while you creating the  trigger,  the region you specify in your trigger must match the region where you linked your repositories.

[image]

Comment: I was able to link one of the repository after reauthorizing my Github account.

Comment: Are you able to list all of your repositories now?

Comment: yes I was able to list all the repositories and select among them.

Comment: How do I reauthorize my Github account? Do I delete the connection and create a new one?